# Weighted least squares fit with measurement uncertainty

Tags: regression, least-squares, measurement-error, uncertainty

I work with geophysics and in my research, some processes are described by power laws

$$k=\gamma v^{\alpha} u^{\beta}$$

To find the indices $(\alpha,\beta)$ the equation is rewritten as a logarithm and then a multiple linear regression model is made,

$$\log_{10}(k) = \alpha \log_{10} (v) + \beta \log_{10}(u) + \log_{10} (\gamma) \\ z = \alpha x + \beta y + c\\ \chi^{2} = \Sigma \frac{(z_{i} - z_{fit,i})^2}{\omega_{i}^{2}};\hspace{1cm} \omega_{i }^{2}=\frac{1}{\sigma_{z,i}^{2} + \alpha^2 \sigma_{x,i}^{2} + \beta^2 \sigma_{y,i }^{2}}$$

where $\omega_{i}$ is the weight of the adjustment given by the uncertainties of the measures ($ k ± Δk , v ± Δv, u ± Δu$). Variables $v$ and $u$ are not correlated.

My questions:

1. Is it a common and correct practice for weights to be given by error propagation in logarithms? Is it one-dimensional? For example:
   $\sigma_{x,i}=Δv/(vln(10)).$
2. $\omega_{i}$ is defined as a function of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. It is correct to first do multiple linear regression without the weights $(\omega_{i})$ to get a pair of parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then use these parameters and redo the regression? Or does $(\omega_{i})$ not need $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: When you took logs, why did the $\log(\gamma)$ term disappear?

Comment: It doesn't disappear. I actually forgot to put it on.

Comment: If you have measurement uncertainty in the $x$'s, the usual weighted least squares regression is biased.  see for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This link shows the Deming regression. Looks better than least squares fits.